# posting HTTP-BODY data with Needle api in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

Hi I'm trying to interact with an HTTP api and I am required to send an HTTP post request some form data. And then in the HTTP-BODY element I am required to supply some more data (can be either csv or xml). So my challenge is in understanding how to do this via the Needle API as its unclear via just the documentation.

I have been able to successfully do :

```
needle.post( host, formdata, function( err, resp, body){ });
```

The above works for the situations where I don't require posting the HTTP-BODY content.

I have tried the following but receive an error :

```
options = {
             headers : { 'Content-Type': 'text/tab-separated-values; charset=iso-8859-1'},
             body : text
          }
needle.post( host, formdata, options, function( err, resp, body){ });
```

Could any one guide me to the correct way to do this somewhat basic task.

Thanks.

Comment: I solved it using the excellent Restler package

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the Restler package and ditched Needle. Needle looks great and I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I couldn't figure it out in time.

https://github.com/danwrong/restler